# Perl syntax error, but I can't find it for the life of me

Tags: perl, syntax-error

This error is angering me. I can't see anything near those lines with a parenthesis error or missing brackets.  Someone give me a hand?  This is my first post, forgive me if the formatting is off; I think I got it right.

EDIT: line 87, the ');' error, is this line: select(SEXTANT_DAEMON_LOG);

```
syntax error at -edited- line 87, near ");"
syntax error at -edited- line 92, near "if"
syntax error at -edited- line 99, near "if"
Unmatched right curly bracket at -edited- line 102, at end of line
syntax error at -edited- line 102, near "}"
syntax error at -edited- line 109, near "}"
syntax error at -edited- line 120, near ");"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at -edited- line 122.
```

This is the code near the error ([full code here](http://pastebin.com/vMB3LjJD)):

```
$MAIN_DBH = getConnection('Main');
$fs_logfile = getCSConfigValue($MAIN_DBH, 'Log', 'Sextant Update Daemon') or die "pid$$[" . localtime(time()) . "] Main dbh error: " . DBI::errstr;
open(SEXTANT_DAEMON_LOG, '>>', $fs_logfile) or die "pid$$[" . localtime(time()) . "] unable to open log file '$fs_logfile'\n";
$tmp = select(SEXTANT_DAEMON_LOG);
$| = 1;
select(SEXTANT_DAEMON_LOG);
```

Comment: If you _need_ to post that much code, use a pastebin. As it is, you only need to post a line or two surrounding the lines which generate the errors.

Comment: sorry, removed the extra and posted a pastebin link

Comment: use IO::Handle;SEXTANT_DAEMON_LOG->autoflush(1); would be more readable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perl isn't giving a very good error message, but what it's actually complaining about is that `"pid$$["` looks like an invalid attempt to access the array `@$`.  Try replacing it with `"pid$$\["`.

The way I found that was by inserting [`__END__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) near the reported location of the first error.  I moved it up and down until I found the first line that caused an error, which was

```
$fs_logfile = getCSConfigValue($MAIN_DBH, 'Log', 'Sextant Update Daemon') or die "pid$$[" . localtime(time()) . "] Main dbh error: " . DBI::errstr;
```

Then I tried adding the backslash, and it fixed the error.

Note:  [`perl -c`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-c%2a) is very useful in situations like this.

Comment: That was it! Augh, thank you for the response.  I didnt even think of that.

Comment: Always using single quotes when you don't intend to expand something is a good way to avoid such errors.

Comment: @musiKk, he did intend to expand `$$`, so single quotes wouldn't have worked.  He just didn't intend Perl to think it was an array subscript.

Comment: @cjm: Oops. Seems like you're right. `$$` is not in my active perlvar memory... ;)